# Transform.RotateAround but specify an end position?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How would I write code that instead of updating to rotate around a fixed point *by a certain number of degrees* every frame (as is built-in to Unity)...

```
void Update() {
    myTransform.RotateAround( myFixedPoint, degreesPerFrame )
}
```

...can rotate around a fixed point *towards an end destination*

```
RotateAroundTowards( myCurrentPosition, myFixedPoint, myEndPosition, durationInSeconds );
```

It would need to calculate the radius and number of degrees between the myCurrentPosition and myFixedPoint, and the myEndPosition and myFixedPoint, somehow?

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. I think you are mixing up [Transform.RotateAround](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) and [Transform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) and are using the wrong terminology. Perhaps you could make a sketch of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact math functions, but here is a rough outline on how to accomplish what I think you want:

- Calculate your current angle from the fixed point
- Calculate the angle to your end point
- Calculate the difference in degrees, track this in a private var
- Use a private var to track the time elapsed... for 1.5 seconds, set a double var to 1500 (ms), and subtract the timelapsed each frame.
- Use the time elapsed each frame, combined with the total degrees to change, to see how far a given frame should rotate
- Use RotateAround with the given frame rotation degrees.
- If you're "close enough", or the time has elapsed, you might want to "snap" the rotation/position to where the object is supposed to be.

For the initial functions... look up triangle function calculations... Rise over Run... Sin/Cos/Tan, etc. That should allow you to "convert" 2 points into angles.